# JPicker opens up and gets stuffed in small viewing portal for accordion

Tags: jquery

In summary, Jpicker is great; however, I have the small box button in a JQuery accordion, the window opens in the accordion and the issue is that the accordion is to small.

Is there a way to have the jpicker open up in the document window, NOT the accordion window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you not use

`position: {x: 'screenCenter', y: 'top'}`